# How do I restart a Unity session from the terminal?

Tags: unity, restart

The command for restarting Gnome2 is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

What is the equivalent for Unity?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Upstart way is

`sudo service lightdm restart` for newer versions using **lightdm**

or `sudo service gdm restart` for older versions using **gdm**.

**Update:**
Another option, which isn't using the terminal but using a key combination, can be found at [How to set keyboard combination to kill the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39571/how-to-set-keyboard-combination-to-kill-the-server)

Comment: I found this very practical and functional way, thank you.

Comment: The service `gdm` does not seem to be available in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `nohup compiz --display :0 --replace &` seems to restart unity without losing your current session's windows. See http://askubuntu.com/a/38597/35666

Answer (score 98):

The command `unity` can be used to restart unity. It restarts the window manager, so your open programs will stay intact and you will not be logged out.

If you run the command from a terminal app, you should add `& disown` to detach it from the terminal. If you don't, then the unity program will become a child process of the terminal app such that when you close the terminal, unity will also close.

It might also be worthwhile to add `&> /dev/null` (before the disown bit) so that text and error output does not clutter your terminal.

So, the command is:

```
unity &> /dev/null & disown
```

If you can't open the terminal application due to the desktop being extremely unresponsive (or any other reason), you can open a purely text-based terminal by hitting `alt-ctrl-F1` through `F6`.

There you will get a text terminal, you have to login first.

Then you can run the command above, then hit `alt-ctrl-F7` or `alt-ctrl-F8` to come back to the graphical desktop.

This tends to fix "hanging" problems.

As a side note: since Unity is a compiz plugin, you can restart unity by restarting compiz using the command:

```
compiz --replace
```

If you run it from the `alt-ctrl-F1` terminal, you will need a `--display` parameter

```
compiz --display :0 --replace
```

You'll still need to add `& disown`

Comment: Thanks. I think this one is better than the accepted one because it only restarts Unity, not the whole display server. Thanks!

Comment: wow! I've been using Ubuntu for 4 years (maybe not that much, but still...) and wasn't aware of the existence of `& disown`. Thank you!

Comment: And another point for Linux over Windows. Restarting your crashed UI without loosing anything: Check!

Comment: Just a minor thing. If you are using any shell other than bash (I use fish), use nohup instead if disown. nohup goes at the begining of the command, like this: ```nohup compiz --display :0 --replace &```

Comment: If you are using unity-2d, you can do `unity-2d-shell &> /dev/null & disown`

Comment: Be careful, the command "unity &> /dev/null & disown" was suggested in answer http://askubuntu.com/a/38597/672893 will kill all your open applications in Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity 7.2.6.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my bacon!   I did `unity &> /dev/null & disown` on Ubuntu 16.04 and it kept all my windows alive.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to open a tty. In most cases Alt-F2 still works. Just enter "unity". That's it. No & disown needed.

Comment: It killed some apps, like Chrome, but otherwise just running `unity` from the panel worked

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 13.04 you can use the following:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal, run nohup compiz --replace. The nohup command will make sure compiz isn't closed when you close the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The command to restart GDM is `sudo stop gdm` followed by `sudo start gdm`, and should be done from a tty.

If you are trying to restart unity itself just run `unity` (but remember you need to do this from the run dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I like to change GNOME's font size attribute depending on the monitor.  I've been shutting down the programs directly so the window position is saved.  I put this in the script which probably does pretty much the same thing:

```
    nautilus -q && sleep 2 && bgcmd nautilus -n
    pkill unity-panel
    pkill unity-window
    sleep 1
    unity-window-decorator &> /dev/null & disown
```