# How to set keyboard combination to kill the X server?

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, restart

It used to be `ctrl+alt+backspace` to kill x server, but for some unknown reason, it was decided to disable that combination and use something else (I think it is `right alt + printscreen +k`).

So, how to enable `ctrl+alt+backspace`?

I have seen it can be done with installing dontzap, but I know there is a way to set that combination from system setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Gnome:*

Open the keyboard preferences (Search for keyboard in Dash), go to the *Layout* tab and press Options. Open *Key sequece to kill the X server* and toggle *Control + Alt + Backspace*

[image]

*KDE:*

*I don't run KDE so I can't verify it or make a pretty screenshot, but according to the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/DontZap), you do as follows:*

- Open System Settings

*KDE 4.1 - KDE 4.5*

- Select "Regional & Language"
- Select "Keyboard Layout".
- Click on "Enable keyboard layouts" (in the Layout tab).
- Select the "Advanced" tab. Then select "Key sequence to kill the X server" and enable "Control + Alt + Backspace".

*KDE 4.6+*

- Select Input Devices under the heading Hardware
- Select Advanced Tab
- Click on Configure Keyboard Options
- Enable "Key sequence to kill the X server" and enable "Control + Alt + Backspace".

Comment: Is that for gnome or KDE? I am using KDE, and I can not find `keyboard preferences` anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. I found a KDE solution, but I haven't verified it.

Comment: doh it was so simple. And I opened that page, but missed `kill x server` page. thanks

Comment: I tried to disable it but it seems to take no effect: that combo still kills "everything" :( any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: For Ubuntu 21.10, I now find that this is available as part of the Gnome Tweaks application https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution which is independent of Gnome/KDE/Fluxbox or any Desktop Environment or Window Manager, try the following. This command is part of the X Window System.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/DontZap#Using_the_command_line

> Using the command line
>
> You can type the following command to enable Zapping immediately.
>
> `setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp`
>
> If you're happy with the new
>   behaviour you can add that command to your `~/.xinitrc` in order to make
>   the change permanent.

I have provided more information in my answer to [10.10 How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace/81394#81394)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the keyboard preferences, choose layout and then options. You will find the ctrl+alt+backspace there, just tick it and your good to go

Comment: Where are the keyboard preferences? Do I need to install a package?

Comment: You will find this in 'applications' its called "keyboard"

Comment: I don't see `applications` anywhere. Are you using KDE or gnome?

Comment: Perhaps you can't do this as this is a gnome setting I think

Comment: There is a way, but it was changed. See Egil's answer, as it is correct