# Move window to workspace problem with disappearing window

Tags: compiz, 13.10, workspaces

When I want move window to some workspace by right click on top and in menu select move right or move to workspace (number) window disappear and i cant find it but app still running ? But when I keyboard shortcut SHIFT + CTRL + ALT + RIGHT work well .

Please help me with this problem ?

Comment: You can find if the apps are still running by using `top` or `ps -u YOUR_USERNAME` in the terminal. Updating may help - run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get update`. Other than that, I have not the foggiest - are you using Unity, and on what version of Ubuntu? You can also change the compiz settings by running `ccsm`.

Comment: I using Unity and Ubuntu 13.10. App still running but i cant find it on workspace or in unity launcher

Comment: Have you tried restarting the window manager / Unity? Can't remember how to it since 11.04, but these links might help: [Link 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38579/how-do-i-restart-an-unity-session-from-the-terminal), [Link 2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager), [Link 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39571/how-to-set-keyboard-combination-to-kill-the-x-server),