# Accidentally unchecked Unity in system settings - blank desktop?

Tags: unity

Accidentally unchecked "unity" in system settings. Now my Ubuntu 11 boots into a "desktop background only" screen. no panels, no icons. Although I was able somehow to invoke Nautilus.

any way I can launch the system settings process and change that? or am I doomed to format my machine and re-install everything?

Comment: Check this post, i think it might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38579/how-do-i-restart-an-unity-session-from-the-terminal

Comment: By system settings are you referring to Compiz Config Settings Manager?

Comment: yes @RolandTaylor

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you managed to run nautilus, but either way:

- Open a nautilus window and press <kbd>ctrl+l</kbd>.
- Type in `/usr/share/applications` in the location bar, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Find the launcher for `ccsm`(Compiz Config Settings Manager).
- Run it by double clicking, and enable Unity from within the window again.

Unity should start again (if compiz is actually running). If it is not, then from here you have two options:

Either:

- Log out and log in again.

Or:

- Find the launcher for the terminal.

  - Open the terminal and type in `unity & disown` (the whole line highlighted in grey including &).
  - This should get you Unity again, and from here you should have no issues.