# How can I programmically set the gnome-terminal title?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How can I programmically set the gnome-terminal title? I've tried

```
gnome-terminal --title="bla"
```

but this opens a new terminal window while outputting

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this to work

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;g0\007"'
```

If this did not change your terminal title you will first have to open  `~/.bashrc`. Find the line that says:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Comment out this line, by putting a `#` character in front of it:

```
# PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Now add this line (you may want to put it just after the commented-out line):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Terminal title name change here\007"'
```

Replace **`Terminal title name change here`** with whatever you want to change the Terminal title to be, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

`gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`

find `Name=Terminal`

change to `Name=whatever you want`

save restart

name changed

IS that what you wanted ?

Or another way without leaving the terminal

`cd /usr/share/applications`

`sudo sed -i 's/Terminal/Your new name here/' gnome-terminal.desktop`

to see the name change appear on the icon in launcher you must also restart unity

`unity &> /dev/null & disown`

for more info about unity restart read https://askubuntu.com/a/38597/71679

`

Comment: Wanted a way to do it without restarting the terminal window.

Comment: ok is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Got this to work PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;g0\007"'

Answer (score 0):

The gnome-terminal option --title is often overridden by your .bashrc file which updates your terminal (or tab) title as the prompt changes.

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Other posts have recommended commenting out this logic in the .bashrc, but this disables all terminals from tracking the prompt, which is sometimes useful.

To add an optional control modify your .bashrc to add an environment variable which when set, skips tying your terminal (tab) title to the prompt:

```
if [ -z "$BASHRC_SKIPPS1" ]
then
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac
fi
```

Now, to invoke a terminal with a static title use:

```
$ BASHRC_SKIPPS1=true gnome-terminal --title="static title"
```

and to open a new tab in an existing terminal with a static title use:

```
$ BASHRC_SKIPPS1=true gnome-terminal --title="static title" --tab
```

To open a terminal with the title tracking the prompt use:

```
$ gnome-terminal
```

or a terminal tab with the title tracking the prompt use:

```
$ gnome-terminal --tab
```