# Numix circle icon for emacs/dash not working

Tags: 14.04, themes, icons

I just installed and started using numix circle icons on Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately, the icons for dash search and Emacs haven't changed, either in the dash or on the launcher, even though all the other ones have. Does anybody know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured this out. The secret is to find the `.desktop` file (for me, this was `/usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop`), and open it with `sudo` in the text editor of your choice. Then, you can edit the `icon` line to point to your desired icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes applications use their own paths for the icon.

In this case, Emacs uses the following path:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/emacs24.svg
```

To change this behaviour, the file `emacs24.desktop` can be changed.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop
```

Replace this line:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/emacs24.svg
```

with this line:

```
Icon=emacs
```

After that, it may be necessary to [restart "Unity"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38579/how-do-i-restart-an-unity-session-from-the-terminal):

```
unity &> /dev/null & disown
```