# Why does the Search/Dash menu flash once and disappear when I tap Super key?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Whenever I tap the Super key to try and open the Dash/Search (I don't know the actual name), it just flashes once and disappears. I get the same results clicking the Launcher icon. I know it's not a problem with my keyboard because of that. Otherwise, it can be a problem with either the actual os, or a problem created by another program (possibly Unity Tweak Tool). And I think it sometimes works, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The HUD used to work fine. I did install the Tweak tool (to get sloppy pointer focus).

Restarting unity (see [How do I restart a Unity session from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38579/how-do-i-restart-an-unity-session-from-the-terminal)) made the HUD come back.